# Accessing MySQL data from python built-in console of QGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, mysql

I'm writing a QGIS Plugin, and somewhere I want to present data from a `MySQL` database. It's simple data(strings,etc), not Geospatial, or vector data. I'm familiar with querying databases from python scripts, and now I want to present data inside a `TextBrowser QT Widget` inside QGIS.

However, I can't import `MySQLdb` from built-in console, neither from my `xxx.py` file inside my plugin folder. From the Apple Terminal i can import MySQLdb with no problems.

I've read [Why can't I import my script from the python console?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27476/why-cant-i-import-my-script-from-the-python-console), but still have no success, because when I call `import MySQLdb` inside a script that resides on a folder added to `sys.path`, it still fails.

Calling  `import MySQLdb` from built-in console tells:

```
import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 309, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 309, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/_mysql.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/_mysql.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/Arthur/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg-tmp/_mysql.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/Arthur/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg-tmp/_mysql.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

ACKNOWLEDGE:

..mach-o, but wrong architecture -> this reveals a mismatch between python-mysqldb-mysql architecture!

The problem is that MySQLdb, does not support python2.7, as compiling for x86_64!
Even if python and mysql-server are 64bits. Switching to python2.6, MySQLdb compiles a x86_64 binary; but QGIS 1.8 is built against python 2.7, so still does not work.
Is it possible to select python framework inside QGIS?

This was very helpful -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327737/error-importing-mysqldb-in-python-2-7-2-on-mac-osx-10-8-1

Comment: Have you installed from the python interpreter ships with qgis? I don't know much about Mac OsX environment.